# How often does trove's challenges reward change?

Tags: trove

Current reward for [challenges](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Challenges) is Bone Dragon Cache. I know before it was Azulian Dragon Cache (you can see it on the screen show at the above wiki's link) and others.

How often does it change? **When will be next change?** Is there rewards rotation, or each time developers introduce a completely new reward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenges are supposed to be rotated on a monthly basis, but they seem to have been a little inaccurate with them.  "Roughly a month" seems about the best answer anybody can give.

As for repeating rewards, so far they haven't brought back any old dragon caches, or even old adventure boxes save for holiday ones from last year, although they did do an event where adventure boxes from any series could be randomly collected in one month, where I guess they couldn't come up with anything new.

Comment: So you mean, that change comes "Roughly at the 1 day of each month"?

Comment: "an event where adventure boxes from any series could be randomly collected in one month" - could you give more information here? What is this event?

Comment: Instead of having a new type of adventure box for one of the more recent rotations, they just reused the old ones and made it so you could get drops from *any* of the previous sets (cookiephant, budgie buddy, etc)

Comment: @klm123 and yeah, that seems to be what they're aiming for.  I think August's came on the 28th, I don't remember the other dates but they've been trying to make it monthly

Comment: So how to get those random drops?

Comment: The current set of adventure boxes are the TurkeyTopia boxes.  They change those up along with the dragon caches.  Adventure boxes randomly drop when defeating enemies, so clearing the enemies in dungeons is the best way to get them.

Answer (score 0):

*"When will be next change? Is there rewards rotation, or each time developers introduce a completely new reward?"*

I came to this game when Bone Dragon was introduced and it seems like they plan on giving us new dragon each month so I guess the only way to get the old ones is to buy souls on market or craft the souls at **Dragon Crucible**(Hub droagon-ish underground, market) using dragon coins which you aquire from these caches.

Also it's good to mention that the **last week of month**, you get **double** souls for daily challenge.